# I'm trying to play one video with html and then when it finishes, replace it with a loop video, please

Tags: html, video

I cant figure out how to post code.

I have already tried searching for an answer to above question.

Maybe I could even cover the video with an image that is the same size when its finished?

Comment: to post a block of code, just insert it and indent it with 4 spaces

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code

```
<video controls loop>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```